# Inverting of Boolean variable not happening after end of every for loop

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, pattern-matching

I am trying to create a pattern as follows -

```
1
0 1
1 0 1
0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1
```

My output is -

```
1
0 1
0 1 0
1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1
```

My code is as follows -

```
N=5
bool_ = True
for row in range(1,N+1):
    for i in range(1, row+1):
        if i>1:
            print(' ', end='')
        print(int(bool_), end= '')
        bool_ =  not bool_
    print()
```

Not sure what is wrong in this. It seems like something to do with range of second for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the first character of a line is the same as the last character of the previous line, so the logic to always toggle the boolean will not work.

The int you could use is `1 - (row + i) % 2`:

```
    print(1 - (row + i) % 2, end= '')
```

You don't need the `bool_` name for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing alternative solution. I am still wondering why boolean toggle logic won't work.

Comment: It's because it doesn't always toggle from 1 to 0. Sometimes the sequence has to be 1 followed by a 1. Imagine the desired output to be all on one line, then you get `101101010110101...` Do you see how there are sometimes two consecutive 1s? The line breaks hide this a bit, but since you toggle the boolean after *every* output of a digit, it will go wrong.